# Using Silverlight common code base for data intensive web and windows application

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-4.0, windows

Recently in a conversation, someone suggested me to make use of Silverlight if I am targeting a web client and a windows client for the same application. This will cut down my effort for supporting the contrast in both presentation layers.

Mine is a product, that will be deployed in enterprises. Both web and windows clients are desirable.

With the above context, I have few queries:

- Is it advisable to adopt the recommended approach and whether this approach is becoming a trend?
- Besides, some configuration & deployment tweaking, will this significantly reduce effort on the presentation layer?
- Is there a possibility that my future prospects (for this product) will resist Silverlight footprint?
- Will I be able to make use of the ASP.Net MVC pattern?
- Will there be any performance implication for the web client?
- Will Silverlight support incremental load of controls?
- If my back-end includes SSRS, will I be able to harness all its front end features with Silverlight?
- Will I be able to support additional devices with same code base in future?
- Mine is a very data intensive application from both, data entry and reporting perspective. Is it advisable to use 3rd party controls (like Telerik) for improved user experience and developer productivity?
- Are their any professional quality open source Silverlight controls (library) available?

Further, I seek information of best practices in the context I shared above.

Answer (score 0):

[Single Sourcing WPF and Silverlight](http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/Single-Sourcing-WPF-and-Silverlight.aspx)

Also, if you organize your projects into various layers, it will become easier.

Comment: At this level, when I am not conversant with either WPF or Silverlight, the link is a little difficult to understand. Moreover, the writer is discussing that he is in a spot where he has a pure WPF app and now he needs to 'Silverlight enable' it and that is the route he takes thereon. The writer also states "Microsoft people recommend that if you are starting a new application that you develop the Silverlight version first" but does not share the relevant link. I am right now talking at the conceptual level and feasibility standpoint. Thanks.